# My sprite rects are flipped vertically in Unity Sprite Editor after being processed by code

Tags: unity, c#, spritesheet

I'm currently trying to process an Adobe Animate XML file with a Unity editor script, and I'm a lot of the way there, my parsing is complete, and I'm able to get some form of output, however the SpriteRects being produced are flipped vertically.

[image: The Unity Sprite Editor displaying my sprite rects upside down]

This output seems to persist no matter what I try. My code that produces that exact output is as follows:

```
List<SpriteRect> spriteMetadata = new List<SpriteRect>();

foreach (AnimateXMLItem item in ParsedAXML)
{
    Vector2 fixedOffset = item.offset;

    float adjustedY = item.offset.y - item.size.y;
    fixedOffset.y = adjustedY;

    SpriteRect metaData = new SpriteRect
    {
        name = item.name,

        rect = new Rect(fixedOffset, item.size),
        pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f)
    };

    spriteMetadata.Add(metaData);
}

var factory = new SpriteDataProviderFactories();
factory.Init();
var dataProvider = factory.GetSpriteEditorDataProviderFromObject(spriteSheetImage);
dataProvider.InitSpriteEditorDataProvider();

dataProvider.SetSpriteRects(spriteMetadata.ToArray());

dataProvider.Apply();

AssetImporter dataProviderImporter = dataProvider.targetObject as AssetImporter;
dataProviderImporter.SaveAndReimport();
```

I'm lost for ideas on how to fix it at this point, I've tried subtracting from image height also, and other math stuff, but they always seem to cause the sprite rects to leave the main texture's bounds, mostly from the bottom.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the sprite is stored flipped and that you dont see it from the wrong side in your editor or have by chance the GO flipped to which you assigned it?

Comment: I am sure, as far as I know the sprite rects are flipped due to Animate storing them with the top left being the 0,0 point, but Unity uses bottom left as 0,0 point.